# Concatenate excel cells with numbers without summing

Tags: r, excel, concatenation

I know you can use the concatenate function in excel to combine two strings in two different cells into one cell, but how do I do the same for cells with numbers in them? I have two columns as seen in the image below (I have started the process by hand to demonstrate what I want) and I want to concatenate the value to read into R to perform a choice experiment evaluation on the data but using concatenate sums the values.

[image]

Comment: If you are going to use R, why don't you do every step in R?

Comment: I have no idea what I was doing wrong at first, it was concatenating 1 and 1 and made 2? And because the data sheet needed alot of changes  at the start and it made more sense to do everything in excel and have a clean data sheet to use in R than arbitrarily draw a line of when to do things in R and things in excel

Comment: Found the problem I had originally, when you choose the default concatenate and click the cells you want to concatenate it sums the cells by default, end of a long day I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the & sign

```
=A1&C1
```

concatenate does also work in excel

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,C1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do the concatenation within R itself, by setting the column type to  string, and then using the paste0(string1, string2) function.